# Can Sony Smart Glass be used on platforms other than Android?

Tags: sony, sony-smarteyeglass

Anybody know, does the Sony SmartGlass SDK support use outside of Android?

For example use with windows/ Linux via a bluetooth connection?

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is only SDK available for Android devices. Also the host application, which is responsible for accessory - host device communication is available only for Android.

For more information, please see [online documentation](https://developer.sony.com/develop/wearables/smarteyeglass-sdk/api-overview/software-architecture/).